# How to reference to old version of nuget package, when another package we are referencing to, is using the newer version

Tags: .net, nuget-package

I have a .net project, lets call it project "A".
 This project references to nuget package "B".
 Project "A" also references to an old version of nuget package c - "C1". 
The nuget package "B" references to a newer version of package c - "C2".

Now in runtime I see that my project "A" is using the newer version of c - "C2", although it references to the old one.

How can I tell my project "A" to use the old c?